# We deal $5$ cards from a deck of $52. $ Let $X=$ Number of Aces among chose card. Find E(X).

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is an example question from my textbook that I do not understand.

The solution states, if we define an indicator function $I_{i}$ that equals 1 when the $i^{th}$ card is an ace, and zero otherwise.

Clearly X=$\Sigma_{i=1}^{5}I_{i}$.

They state that, since we are sampling without replacement, $I_{i}$ are all identically distributed. Therefore the solution they give is $E(X)=5E(I_{1})=5 \cdot \frac{4}{52}$ (text book solution).

However, if they are sampling without replacement, wouldn't the individual probabilities change?

I.e. $I_{1}=P(1^{st} card \ is \ ace)=\frac{4}{52}$

$I_{2}=P(2^{nd} card \ is \ ace)=\frac{3}{51} $

etc.

The solution I would have come up with is
$E(X)=E(I_{1})+...+E(I_{5})=\frac{4}{52}+\frac{3}{51}+\frac{2}{50}+\frac{1}{49}+0.$
Why is this not correct?

Comment: the way you wrote $I_2$, it's the probability the second card is an ace assuming the first card is an ace

Comment: "we deal" implies the joint distribution of the five $I_i$ values is symmetric with respect to permutations.  So the $EI_i$ are all equal. The fact that $E(I_1+\cdots +I_5)=EX_1+ \cdots +EI_5$ does not depend on any replacement/non-replacelment assumptions.

Comment: Sampling without replacement means that those indicator RV's are no longer independent -- however, that doesn't change the linearity of expectation, which holds regardless of independence/dependence. So the expected value of the sum is the same either way.

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote $I_2$, it's the probability the second card is an ace assuming the first card is an ace (i.e., assuming there are $3$ aces and $51$ cards left in the deck).
The probability the first card is an ace is only $\frac 4 {52}$.

You must add the probability that the second card is an ace assuming the first card is *not* an ace.  The probability the first card is not an ace is $\frac {48} {52}$, and the probability the second card is an ace in that scenario is $\frac {4}{51}$.

So looking at it this way comes to the result in the textbook, since $$\frac 4{52} \frac 3{51}+\frac {48}{52} \frac 4 {51}= \frac 4{52}\left(\frac3{51}+\frac{48}{51}\right)=\frac4{52}$$
is the probability the second (and in fact each) card is an ace.